# Swift URL resourceSpecifier is unavailable

Tags: ios, swift, url, swift3

I am translating code from Objective-C to Swift 3 and as I write this code

```
   let url = URL(string:"http://example.com/index.html")
   var formattedURL:String = url!.resourceSpecifier
```

I get an error  " 'resourceSpecifier' is unavailable: Use `path`, `query`, and `fragment` instead ". How do I resolve this?

Comment: `resourceSpecifier` is a property of `NSURL`. While normally you use `URL` in Swift 3, you can still use `NSURL`.

Comment: What is the equivalent of resourceSpecifier in URL?

Comment: There isn't one, that's the issue. You could just strip off the scheme and colon to get the same result.

Answer (score 5):

You can bridge `URL` to `NSURL`

```
let url = URL(string:"http://example.com/index.html")!
let formattedURL = (url as NSURL).resourceSpecifier
```

Comment: Or just use `NSURL` to begin with if this is the only use of it.

Comment: What is the equivalent of resourceSpecifier in URL is my main interest. I know I can use NSURL anyday.

Comment: `resourceSpecifier` is not implemented in `URL`. You could consider the compiler suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

```
url.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\(url.scheme ?? "")://", with: "")
```